# Activity of a radioactive source - distribution of number of impulses per unit time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity, statistics

I have the following problem:

The activity of a radioactive isotope was measured with the result $N=625$ impulses/second. If this measurement were to be repeated, state the interval where we can say $N$ will be with 95% certainty.

Now this question boils down to determining the distribution of the random variable $N$. Radioactive decay makes me think of the exponential distribution, but that would be if the question was asking for some sort of expected time, I think.

I considered a Poisson distribution as well, but that's for rare events, and $625$ impulses per second doesn't seem to indicate that an impulse is a rare event.

So should I just assume that $N$ is normally distributed?

Comment: Why do you believe that Poisson distributions are only for rare events? If you sampled a nanosecond, than it would be rare to find an event, would it not?

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. But is a Poisson process appropriate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from Wikipedia ([Poisson Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)):

> In probability theory and statistics, the Poisson distribution (French pronunciation [pwasɔ̃]; in English usually /ˈpwɑːsɒn/), named after French mathematician Siméon Denis Poisson, is a discrete probability distribution that expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time and/or space if these events occur with a known average rate and independently of the time since the last event.

The probability of any one atom decaying is independent of the decay of any other atom. Assuming a single decay channel, the average rate of decay is known. One also has to assume that the observed decays are not significantly depleting the remaining atoms that could decay.  Given these, using Poisson statistics is not just possible, but highly desirable.